# How to PDF Resize generated by rdlc and itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext, rdlc

I have generated pdfs using rdlc and then combined multiple pdf files to a single document using iTextSharp pdfsmartcopy class. But my pdf size is large and I want to reduce the size of that pdf file. I have tried compressing it using iTextSharp but that's unable to compress it. When I upload the pdf file to ilivepdf.com online for compression ,then it compresses the 21MB file to 1MB.

Comment: Please share your source code and your pdf files. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Often, the problem is related to embedded fonts.

You see, PDF really strives to preserve your document exactly how you made.

To do that, a PDF library can decide to embed a font. You can imagine this as simply putting the font file into the PDF document.

**But, here comes the tricky part.**

The PDF specification took into account that this may be overkill.
I mean, if you are only using the 50-something characters typically used in Western languages, it makes little sense to embed the entire font.

So PDF supports a feature called "font subsetting". This means, instead of embedding the entire font, only those characters that are actually used are embedded in the document.

**So what is going wrong exactly when you're merging these documents?**

*(I will skip a lot of the technical details.)*

In order to differentiate between a fully embedded font, system font, or subset embedded font, `iText` generates a new font name for your fonts whenever it embeds them.

So a document containing a subset of Times New Roman might have "Times-AUHFDI" in its resources.

Similarly, a second document (again containing a subset of Times New Roman) might list "Times-VHUIEF" as one of its resources.

I believe it simply adds a random 6-character suffix. (ex-iText developer here)

`PdfSmartCopy` has to decide what to do with these resources. And sadly, it doesn't know whether these fonts are actually the same. So it decides to embed both these subsets into the new document.

This is a huge memory penalty.
If you have 100 documents, all using a subset of the same font, that subset will be embedded 100 times.

The other tool you listed might actually check whether these fonts are the same (and if they are, embed them only once). Or the other tool might simply not care that much and assume based on the partial name match that they are the same.

The ideal solution would of course be to compare the actual characters in the font, to see whether these two subsets can be merged.

But that would be much more difficult (and might potentially be a performance penalty).

**What can you do?**

1. There are 12 fonts that are never embedded. They are assumed to be present on every system (hence why they are never embedded.)

   If you have control over the process that generates the PDF documents, you could simply decide to create them using only these fonts.
2. Alternatively you could write a smarter `PdfSmartCopy`. You would need to look into how fonts are built and stored, and perform the actual comparison I mentioned earlier.
3. Ask for technical support at iText. If enough people request this particular feature, you may get it.